# Select subarray without copying into new buffer?

Tags: java, arrays

I have `float[] array` of length 100. Is there a way I can select (pseudocode):

```
x = array[10:19];
```

To get elements 10,11,12,...,19 without copying over into another buffer? I'm in a mobile application where I don't want to waste space or time doing this. I'd rather just reference the pointers the system uses for `array`.

Comment: How you you access the result? When working with floats, the only way NOT to copy would be to reference the original array. So if you keep indices like `start = 10` and `end = 19`, then you can access it like `array[start + (length - 1)]`

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do this would be to use [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), which is much faster and more efficient than copying manually using a loop. It will require another array, but any approach you use (beyond just passing the original array around with a couple of ints representing the offset to use) will do this, and it's relatively cheap - the memory consuming bit is usually the objects that it's referencing rather than the array itself, and they are not copied.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no API to do that. The closest solution to this would be building your own class that wraps an existing array, and does the re-indexing:

```
class SubArray {
    private final float[] data;
    private final int offset;
    private final int length;
    public SubArray(float[] data, int offset, int length) {
        this.data = data;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.length = length;
    }
    public float get(int index) {
        if (index >= length) throw ...
        return data[index + offset];
    }
    public void set(int index, float value) {
        if (index >= length) throw ...
        data[index + offset] = value;
    }
}
```

If the result that you need is a new object that behaves like an array in all respects, including the indexing operator, you would need to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

(**Update**) Precondition: You should store the data in a `Float[]` instead of a `float[]`, the performance-hit should be minimal.

You can use: `Arrays.asList(array).subList(10, 20)`.

The `Arrays.asList(array)` does the following:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

And then `.subList(10, 20)` returns you a `List`.

Then if you really want to work with arrays in the end, you could take the following lines:

```
List<Float> subList = Arrays.asList((Float[])array).subList(10, 20);
Float[] subArray = subList.toArray(new Float[subList.size()]);
```

(**Update**) Changed `Arrays.asList(array)` to `Arrays.asList((Float[])array)` such that it is correct now.

From documentation:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list.
>
> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the list is set to null. (This is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)
>
> Like the toArray() method, this method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs. Further, this method allows precise control over the runtime type of the output array, and may, under certain circumstances, be used to save allocation costs.
>
> Suppose x is a list known to contain only strings. The following code can be used to dump the list into a newly allocated array of String:

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

This should ensure that no data is wasted, the only thing to be careful about could be autoboxing.

**UPDATE:** Changed my answer such that it now is correct under a precondition.

Comment: -1. This won't work for primitive arrays, only for Object arrays.  If you try it, you'll get a single-element `List<float[]>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Updated the answer. Result: Possibly a small performance hit added (autoboxing), but it now works correctly, no need for -1 anymore.

Comment: The toArray() function copies it into your new buffer.  That's against what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem of using a simple for loop? Objects are in java called by reference.
So, executing copying the array does not copy the objects.

```
float[] subarray = new float[10];
for(int i = 10, j = 0; i < 19; i++, j++) {
     subarray[j] = x[i];
}
```

The `array[0]` is a reference to the object of `x[0]`.

edit: This only applies for objects, and i don't know if it also applies to a `float`